# How can I add type3 for random to build scene from 3 type

Tags: javascript, 2d-games

I want to make game2d infinite run. Now I can add block1 and block2 that's made from code from my teacher, but I don't know how to add block3 to make random block for run.

Here's a sample of the code which I am talking about.

```js
   addPlatform(width, x, y, type) {
     let platform;
     if(type == 1){
        platform = this.add.tileSprite(x+width/2, y, width, 32, "block1");
       
     } else {
        platform = this.add.tileSprite(x+width/2, y, width, 32, "block2");
     }
     this.physics.add.existing(platform);
     platform.body.setVelocityX(-200);
     platform.body.setImmovable(true);
     this.platformGroup.add(platform);
}
```

Comment: `} else if (type == 2) {`?

Comment: thank you so much but it's still show only block1 and block2